# The linguistic term for the slogan structure

Tags: terminology, slogan

Recently I've seen this slogan.

[image]

Its spelling and pronunciation are a bit unusual:

"*Nice to **meat** you*" means "it's nice to provide you with some meat dish",

but it sounds like 
"*It's nice to **meet** you*" as if you are introduced to somebody.

My question is: 
How can we name this linguistic phenomenon?

Comment: I have also seen it as "Nice to meat and sea you", when they also carried seafood products.

Comment: I haven't, but it's a very interesting addition to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your slogan is an example of the ***pun***.

According to  Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun):

The pun, also called paronomasia, is a form of word play that exploits multiple meanings of a term, or of similar-sounding words, for an intended humorous or 
rhetorical effect.

These ambiguities can arise from the intentional use of homophonic, 
homographic, 
metonymic, or figurative language.

In your case there is a homophonic pun,
 which uses homophones
 MEAT and MEET.